# How to install android app in system/app directory without rooted device so that user can not uninstall that app

Tags: android, root, android-install-apk

I made an app which I want to install in system/app directory so that user can not uninstall it. but I want to do it without rooting device. as soon as user download app it will be install in system/app directory. 
I want to do this by writing code.
I am aiming that users are not allow to uninstall it.

Comment: any app user is able to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `system` level applications (i.e. preloaded applications like `Gallery`, `Video Player`, `Music Player`, `SystemUI` etc ) resides in `/system/app` folder and they have `super user` (or root equivelent) permission

As programmatically, without rooting device, any 3rd party application cannot be installed to `/system/app/` folder

Comment: i my aiming that user can not uninstall my so how can i do so??

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do without root access**. Once your device gets rooted you manually need to make that app system app. Otherwise there is no way to so without root. You cant do that just with coding of whatever type you write.

Comment: i my aiming that user can not uninstall my so how can i do so??

Comment: Sorry to say ,this can't happen without root access.

Answer (score 0):

/system is mounted a read-only, you cannot install an app to /system/app unless rooted. If you are running a rooted rom then just do adb remount to make it read-write

Comment: i my aiming that user can not uninstall my so how can i do so??

Comment: If you don't want your app to be deleted you can add as a Device Administrator.Until  they Deactivate app cannot be deleted.